# how to show bahasa malaysia language in android

Tags: android, localization

I got two questions:

1. I need to see Bahasa Malaysia language translation on a spinner in android
2. How to call another program; say Google hangouts into the app?

I already got the translations in values-ms
Please I really need this thanks

Comment: do you wanna show static text?

Comment: i mean the translation i have English, Chinese Simplified translations which shows on the app, but why not bahasa malaysia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer

```
String[] language= { "English", "Chinese (Simplified)", "Bahasa Malaysia"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String

(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,language);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Locale applang = new Locale ("ms");
        switch (arg2){
        case 0:
            config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        break;
        case 1:
            config.locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;
        break;
        case 2:
            config.locale = applang;
        break;
        default:
            config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        break;
        }
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);       
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }
    });
```